# WDS How to use variables from other sampler?

Tags: selenium, jmeter, webdriver

I have Sampler where i switching to child window, but i need to save handle for main window to be able switch to it in another sample:
Pls see screenshots

Sampler with saved handle for main window:
[image]

How can i call it in next Sampler?

[image]

WDS.browser.switchTo().defaultContent() causes an error:

```
ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: no such window: window was already closed
```

Sample A code:

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
var handles = WDS.browser.getWindowHandles()
var mainWindow = WDS.browser.getWindowHandle()
while (handles.size()!=2){
    handles = WDS.browser.getWindowHandles()
    WDS.log.info(handles.size())
}
var iterator = handles.iterator()
var counter = 1;
while (iterator.hasNext())
{
   var handle = iterator.next()
   WDS.browser.switchTo().window(handle)
   WDS.log.info('Window ' + counter + ' title = ' + WDS.browser.getTitle())
   counter++;

}
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

Sample B Code:

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
var timeunit = java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit 
WDS.browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, timeunit.SECONDS)
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium, org.openqa.selenium.support.ui)
var timeunit = java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit 
var wait = new pkg.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 3000)
var ssn = ("078-05-"+WDS.args[0])

//WDS.browser.switchTo().defaultContent()
WDS.browser.switchTo().window(variable mainWindow from SwitchToWorkFlowWindow sampler)

WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: This question is about Jmeter samplers in general.
You dont need to copy code and reproduce it if u dont understand a question

Comment: Question is:
Can i call VAR from sample1  in sample 2

Comment: It's rather ironic that you accuse me of not understanding the question when my comment has nothing to do with understanding the question. It's that you have posted a screenshot of code which is highly discouraged and not needed in this case because it adds nothing of value. Now... did you read the content in the link I posted before **you** answered? If you did, you would have seen a discussion as to why having screenshots of code is a bad idea and discouraged. The attitude in your response is not going to win you much favor here on SO or in life.

Comment: i've added a code, but i dont understand anyway why do nee that.
If u know is it possible to call variable from sample A in sample B.
code is just for example. Screenshot were priveded for understanding that VAR is in another sample

Comment: If you read the link I posted, you will see lots of reasons why this is required... besides the fact that it's part of SO's guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [`WDS.vars`](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) shorthand which is basically an instance of [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class so you can use it to pass data from one sampler to another, like:

1. In first sampler:

   ```
   var foo = 'bar'
   WDS.vars.put('foo', foo)
   ```
2. In second sampler:

   ```
   var foo = WDS.vars.get('foo')
   WDS.log.info('Foo value is: ' + foo)
   ```

   [image: JMeter WebDriver Pass Variables between requests]

You can find some more information on advanced usage of the WebDriver Sampler in the : [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) guide

Comment: Thanks a lot! thats exactly i've looked for!